# Wordpress custom theme - I am unable to display the logowith this code

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

i am making a custom wordpress theme and i have not been able to display the logo correctly. I am using this code to display 'the_custom_logo' but the logo is not showing up.
I have added theme support and uploaded the logo image as well.

```
    <div class="brand">
      <?php
        if(function_exists('the_custom_logo')){
          $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod('custom-logo');
          $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom_logo_id);
        }
       ?>
       <img src="<?php echo $logo[0] ?>" class="logo" alt="">
     </div>
```

However when i try the following code, I am able to get the logo. But it adds all the wordpress generated classes which i don't want. Hence i was trying to work the code above.

```
    <div class="brand">
      <?php
      if(function_exists('the_custom_logo')){
        the_custom_logo();
      }
       ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Id should be underscore  "custom_logo"

```
<div class="brand">
<?php
  if(function_exists('the_custom_logo')){
    $custom_logo_id     = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
    $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom_logo_id);
   }
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $logo[0] ?>" class="logo" alt="">
</div>
```